# Make certain files read only on boot

Tags: linux, grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and GRUB2. I'm wondering if there is a way that, upon booting the kernel, I can have the kernel make certain files read only. I want this status to persist for as long as the OS is running without `sudo` being able to switch it off. I know Linux can lock files in other contexts, so I'd like to know if this is also possible and how I can achieve it.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do this? Is there some automatic process that keeps deleting certain files? As far as I know there is no way to prevent this if you have these files in a read-write filesystem since `su` will override any restrictions. However, you could move those files into a read-only filesystem. In this case there would have to be at least a remount before they could be deleted. Also, you could create hard-links to these files. They would protect the inode from being deleted.

Comment: Why does the kernel need to do it at boot rather than just doing it during a session?  You can restrict sudo permissions, including allowing access to su.

Comment: I"m interested in doing this too. Related article I found about mandatory locking: http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030623.html

Comment: I'm trying to make a novel set up where GRUB and its configuration files are write protected for security purposes. It's supposed to emulate (normal sense of the word) the boot lock processes found on most Android phones. Making it kernel-level makes it harder to undo.

Comment: Maybe you want somethink like SELinux.

Anyway, without root access your config files should be pretty safe.

Comment: I'm kind of doing this for novelty purposes, so making root unable to touch them is important here. Does SELinux have the features I'm describing or is it just some security hardened Linux distribution?